# Send push notifications based on the datetime stored in the database MySQL

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, push-notification

I have a web project. In my project admin can create promotion. When admin create promotion, he set start time of promotion. If current date matches the value of start_time on promotion table, service should send notification to users (Android, iOS). I use MySQL database. In my database has table promotions. In promotions table has start_time column. My question is that: How can I send notification based on datetime which stored in table promotions. I know how can achieve this problem with cron, but i want to know how can i achieve this with Firebase (PHP,LARAVEL).

Comment: cronjob of course..

Comment: @ZeroOne Are there any other options? For example, Cloud Function ?

Comment: A cloud is a service and every service has other offers. One of the common offer is an cronjob like @ZeroOne said. But for example you can run your script with every page load. But that is not realy user friendly.